# How to get response headers from WP REST API in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, next.js

I am fetching some data from WP REST API in Next.js with [Isomorphic unfetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch), how can I get response headers?

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

class Blog extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        const res = await fetch('https://wordpress.org/news/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
        const data = await res.json();
        return { 
            res: res,
            data: data
        };
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.res)
        console.log(this.props.data)
        return (
            <h1>Blog</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

I don't see anything available in the console [image]

but headers are there when I just open [url](https://wordpress.org/news/wp-json/wp/v2/posts) in browser [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

res.headers will returns all headers according to [this](https://github.com/developit/unfetch#responseheaders). You can use res.headers.get('x-wp-total') to get value, then return it inside getInialProps function.

```
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';

class Blog extends React.Component {
    static async getInitialProps() {
        const res = await fetch('https://wordpress.org/news/wp-json/wp/v2/posts');
        const data = await res.json();
        return { 
            res: res,
            data: data,
            wpTotal: res.headers.get('x-wp-total')
        };
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.wpTotal)
        console.log(this.props.data)
        return (
            <h1>Blog</h1>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get undefined, I can only access size and timeout inside this.props.res

Comment: I didn't see your edited post until now. Thank you, this way I do get the values!

Comment: I am getting error as `response.headers.get` is not a function. In my case, I need to get the response before deleting, and GET response headers contains the tag value.

Comment: @Marko getting a related issue, I have to pass headers in further API call. Can you please look in to it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69678380/unable-to-get-axios-response-headers-in-next-js